# Agnostic Screen scraper using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

Lets say I want a screen scraper that doesn't care if you pass it an HTML page, url that goes to an XML Document, or a Url that goes to a text file.

examples:

http://tonto.eia.doe.gov/oog/info/wohdp/dslpriwk.txt

http://google.com

This will work if the page is HTML or a text file:

```
public class ScreenScrapingService : IScreenScrapingService
{
    public XDocument Scrape(string url)
    {
        var scraper = new HtmlWeb();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xml = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        scraper.LoadHtmlAsXml(url, xml);
        var text = stringWriter.ToString();
        return XDocument.Parse(text);
    }
}
```

However; if it is an XML file such as:

http://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/includes/gas_diesel_rss.xml

```
[Test]
public void Scrape_ShouldScrapeSomething()
{
    //arrange
    var sut = new ScreenScrapingService();

    //act
    var result = sut.Scrape("http://www.eia.gov/petroleum/gasdiesel/includes/gas_diesel_rss.xml");

    //assert

}
```

Then I get the error:

```
 An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Is it possible to write this so that it doesn't care what the URL ultimately is?

Comment: Edited with something a bit more tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the exact exception on visual studio `CTR+ALT+E` and enable `CommonLanguageRunTimeExceptions`, it seems like LoadHtmlAsXml expects html, so probably your best bet is to use a `WebClient.DownloadString(url)` and `HtmlDocument` with property `OptionOutputAsXml` set to `true` as the following, when that fails catch it

```
 public XDocument Scrape(string url)
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        var htmlorxml = wc.DownloadString(url);
        var doc = new HtmlDocument() { OptionOutputAsXml = true};
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        doc.Save(stringWriter);
        try
        {
            return XDocument.Parse(stringWriter.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            //it only gets here when the string is xml already
            try
            {
                return XDocument.Parse(htmlorxml);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```